# Angular Universal - Dynamic Meta tags not working on social media sharing

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-universal

I have an app built on Angular 5 and Angular Universal with server side rendering.

For the home page i have fixed a title as "ABC" and when loading the app i have called a constructor which updated the title and meta information for fb and other social media apps.

While loading the website the tags are updated but when i scrap the website on facebook debugger tool it doesn't show the updated tags.

```
Following code runs on ngOnInit(){
    this.title.setTitle('ABC - XYX');
    this.meta.updateTag({name: 'author',content: "ABC.com"});
    this.meta.updateTag({name: 'description',content: "ABC - XYX | ABC - XYX "});
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:type', content: 'website' });
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:site_name', content: 'ABC.com' });
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:title', content: 'ABC - XYX' });
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:description', content: 'ABC - XYX | ABC - XYX' });
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:url', content: "http://abc[dot]com" });
}
```

So can anyone help me on what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: so if you look at the page source (ctrl+U) for a specific page, you've got the wrong meta?

Comment: @David on the page the meta tags are updated correctly but when i go to facebook social debugger then those tags are not fetched.

Comment: it's not a problem with angular then if you have the correct tag when viewing the source.

Comment: @David any pointers on where to look out for this solution. What could be the other reason if not angular? I can share my test server url if you can help with that?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the meta as seen in the source page (ctrl+u)?

Comment: @David check the screenshot here https://ibb.co/mbdG8J

Comment: That's the debugger's elements view, isn't it? Not the source view you get with Ctrl+U ?

Comment: @David yes sorry my mistake. here is the source code https://ibb.co/kVtxhd in this code i'm not getting the updated meta tags but in the debugger i can see.

Comment: There is no meta on that screenshot

Comment: @David yes thats what i checked as well but not able to figure out where the configuration is wrong. While debugging in chrome meta tags are available but on server side rendering they are not.

Comment: @David thanks for pointing out about the view source. I finally figured what was the issue. I was using hammerjs and then domino in server.ts file because of template rendering configuration changed. So now i have to see how to include hammerjs in the project. Thanks for your help

Comment: So does it mean that you had arrors server side that you did not see before?

Comment: No i did resolved the window not defined error that comes with hammerjs but in a way to solve that issue my server configuration changed the rendered template because of which the meta information was over written.

Comment: Hi can you help me with please? Having the similar issue

Comment: Have the same issue right now, the tags are updated but fb doesn't see them

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. I have angular universal enabled already. If the tags are dynamically generated after the API call then its not working. Only hardcoded tags are getting detected.

Answer (score 0):

These meta are added to the DOM after the page is rendered, hence those are not seen by most social medias.

A solution may be to render the page on the server side with [Angular Universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal).

Reading online I saw someone suggesting to use th e*.htaccess* to redirect all the requests to a php script that adds the meta tags.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue after universal integration. Just create the universal-interceptor.ts file and add to your appServerModule.ts file. You can see the below link to see how it is implemented https://angular.io/guide/universal#using-absolute-urls-for-server-requests it will solve this issue